# Google cloud Metrics

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm new to google cloud, I want the metrics for each instance I have like cpu usage and network sent and received, I have this code

```
from typing import Iterable

from google.cloud import compute_v1

def list_instances(project_id: str, zone: str) -> Iterable[compute_v1.Instance]:
    """
    List all instances in the given zone in the specified project.

    Args:
        project_id: project ID or project number of the Cloud project you want to use.
        zone: name of the zone you want to use. For example: “us-west3-b”
    Returns:
        An iterable collection of Instance objects.
    """
    instance_client = compute_v1.InstancesClient()
    instance_list = instance_client.list(project=project_id, zone=zone)

    return instance_list
```

and this, from https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/docs/reference/libraries?hl=pt-br#client-libraries-usage-python

```
from google.cloud import monitoring

client = monitoring.Client()

resource = client.resource(
    type_='gce_instance',
    labels={
        'instance_id': '0000000000000000',
        'zone': 'europe-west1-b',
    }
)

metric = client.metric(
    type_='custom.googleapis.com/my_metric',
    labels={}
)

# Default arguments use endtime datetime.utcnow()
client.write_point(metric, resource, 3.14)
print('Successfully wrote time series.')
```

but when I do this, I get

```
module 'google.cloud.monitoring' has no attribute 'Client'
```

So google docs are not the best how can I access metrics from the list of instances I have?

Answer (score 0):

This error sometimes happens to other google.cloud modules. Try to [install the google-cloud-monitoring library](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/docs/reference/libraries#install) again, as the cause may be from a broken installation of the library/package. Hope this will fix the issue.